# UWP application only connects to Sharepoint when Loopback exempt AND fiddler is running at the same time

Tags: uwp, sharepoint-2013, fiddler, loopback

I have a UWP application that is to connect to sharepoint 2013. Initially the app did not connect at all and I narrowed down the error to a loopback issue. I ran the CMD checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n= to exempt my app from the loopback, however; this only works when fiddler is running. If I shut fiddler down, the app will not login.

I think this must be a proxy issue but I have no idea how to fix this.

The error I get is that the application cannot find the server.

Comment: Could you share more detail about how do you connect to share point, and have configured checknetisolation loopbackexempt command according to this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx#what_you_need_to_know).

Comment: I ran it through command line using the package family name using:
checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=<package family name>

I've read that document before and it hasn't really helped. I do need this on but I also need fiddler running.

I'm connecting via Microsoft.SharePoint.Client Client context.